# Go Template Parse function is giving error

Tags: html, css, go

I am using Go `html/template` package to generate html output. This was working fine but this is giving error:

`"'" in attribute name: "Cabin', sans-serif; text-align: "`

With following html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700);
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,700);
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
  <div style="background:#1A86A2;background-color:#1A86A2;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
            <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                        <div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;line-height:1.5;text-align:left;color:#000000;">
                        <h1 style="font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; color: #ecf0f1;">{{.BookingDate}}</span></h1>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And following code I have used to parse template:

```
    var body string
    t, err := template.New("my_template").Parse(templateHtml)
    if err != nil {
        return body, err
    }
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    if err = t.Execute(buf, data); err != nil {
        return body, err
    }
    body = buf.String()
    return body, nil
```

**Updated:**

When I run this code on playground or separate go program then it works fine.

But I am trying to send this parsed html in email via Amazon SES service.

The code is:

```
body, errParse := ParseTemplate(html, data)
sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String(AwsRegion)},
)

/* Create an SES client in the session */
svc := ses.New(sess)

/* Assemble the email */
input := &ses.SendEmailInput{
    Destination: &ses.Destination{
        CcAddresses: []*string{},
        ToAddresses: []*string{
            aws.String(emailTo),
        },
    },
    Message: &ses.Message{
        Body: &ses.Body{
            Html: &ses.Content{
                Charset: aws.String("UTF-8"),
                Data:    aws.String(body),
            },
        },
        Subject: &ses.Content{
            Charset: aws.String("UTF-8"),
            Data:    aws.String(subject),
        },
    },
}

/* Attempt to send the email */
resp, err := svc.SendEmail(input)


func ParseTemplate(templateHtml string, data interface{}) (string, error) {
    var body string
    t, err := template.New("my_template").Parse(templateHtml)
    if err != nil {
        return body, err
    }
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    if err = t.Execute(buf, data); err != nil {
        return body, err
    }
    body = buf.String()
    return body, nil
}
```

How can I solve this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No error here: https://play.golang.com/p/SEUqJ-xjWqE

Comment: You should mention the system that's returning the error, e.g. the chrome browser, or firefox, or something else, like your ide maybe... Go it is not (it seems).

Comment: @mkopriva I have run it on both firefox and chrome browsers. But its not working.

Comment: @mkopriva I have linux OS (ubuntu) and go version 1.10 installed on it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the single quotes? Does your page break then?

Comment: When I remove the single quotes, it works fine. But in other html when I Ioad this font family it automatically get added with quotes. Can i do it with removing the quotes? Is there any way ? I mean like I have loaded Ubuntu font family also. It gets added with quotes. then why not cabin ?

Comment: It's still unclear to me what is giving you the error, what software is complaining about the single quotes. I've just tried rendering your html, *with* the single quotes, in firefox with no issue.

Comment: As I can see in playground link you have used os.Stdout() instead of bytes.Buffer. I think this is the difference. Please make it with the parsing code which I have provided.

Comment: What I did was take the literal html string you have there in your question and sent that using the http.ResponseWriter, which shows that there's nothing wrong with the html. The problem is what you do with the returned `body` string, how you send the response to the browser,  but you left that out of the question.

Comment: I did not understand I showed up with all the parsing code and html. Anyways how do I fix this ? this code was working fine before this, Do I need to change this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212590/discussion-between-mkopriva-and-lakhvir-singh).

Comment: No error whatsoever: https://gist.github.com/mkopriva/1fa4f253f21c378c67a997a390e60e58

Comment: @mkopriva I have updated the question for my overall problem. Hope I can get the solution.